# Loading more Paged scrollviews in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have an app where I could have upwards of 3000 pages of a paged scrollView but it takes over a minute to load. Is there a way to continuously and instantaneously load more pages of a scrollView as the user scrolls?

Comment: The general solution used to be to make a "tiled scroll view", although I think collection views may also be an option in iOS 6 - but don't quote me on that. Hope that points you int he right direction. As it is now your question is fairly broad and lacks details, so if it gets closed be sure to come edit it with details and your specific problem so it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the new `UICollectionView` layout view (which is a subclass of `UIScrollView`)?  They are like UITableViews in that they can load content on demand, but are far more flexible in presentation.  iOS6 only but at this point that is not unreasonable.